# Cannot load drawing library (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to use google maps with drawing mode.

Here is my View code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon Arrays</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/sitecss">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">
      <div id="mapDiv" class="map"></div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/test.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**********&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing" ></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I need to add drawing mode to map, and here is my script

```
 function initMap() {


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    var mapDiv = map.getDiv();

    map.setOptions({
        fullscreenControl: true,
        scaleControl: true
    });



    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON

            ]
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: 'green',
            fillOpacity: 0.4,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            clickable: true,
            zIndex: 1,
            editable: false
        }
    });
```

It uploads map, all okay. But I don't see drawing panel on map.
In dev console I don't have errors.
Where is can be my problem?

Comment: I get a syntax error with the posted code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.  Are you adding the drawing manager to the map? (add `map:map,` to the `DrawingManagerOptions`)? ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/42kb6rng/))

Comment: Yeah. You're right @geocodezip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot add your drawingManager to the map,try add this at the end of your code :

```
drawingManager.setMap(map);
```